# MySQL left join does not work correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I want to left join 2 tables.
So all attributes of left table should be shown in result table, no matter if it can join with other table or not.

When I do the follwing, I dont get the expected result

```
week_table:
 date       kw note
 ---------- -- ----
 2012-04-01  0 NULL
 2012-04-02  0 NULL

fact_table:
id number_of_application number_of_cluster number_of_jvm number_of_node number_of_was fk_wasversion fk_date    fk_domain fk_osname fk_osarch fk_osversion fk_stage
 -- --------------------- ----------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- ------------- ---------- --------- --------- --------- ------------ --------
  1                   114                 8            80             18            18 6.0           2012-04-01 domain1   Linux     sparc     2            stage1
  2                   114                 8            80             18            18 6.0           2012-04-02 domain1   Linux     sparc     2            stage1
  3                   114                 8            80             18            18 6.0           2012-04-01 domain1   AIX       sparc     2            stage1
  4                   114                 8            80             18            18 6.0           2012-04-02 domain1   Solaris   sparc     2            stage1
```

When I do this:

```
select
  w.date,
  coalesce(sum(f.number_of_was), 0)
from 
  week_table w
    left join fact_table f on (w.date = f.fk_date) 
where f.fk_osname = "AIX" 
group by w.date;
```

I only get :

```
 date       coalesce(sum(f.number_of_was), 0)
 ---------- ---------------------------------
 2012-04-01                                18
```

Expected:

```
date       coalesce(sum(f.number_of_was), 0)
---------- --------------------------------
2012-04-02                         18
```

Does someone know why?

Best Regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Move the criteria on the outer joined table from the WHERE clause to the ON clause:

```
select
  w.date,
  coalesce(sum(f.number_of_was), 0)
from 
  week_table w
    left join fact_table f on (w.date = f.fk_date and f.fk_osname = "AIX") 
group by w.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where f.fk_osname = "AIX"
```

I guess there is only one record with this osname?

Answer (score 0):

because of `where f.fk_osname = "AIX"`

if the data doesnt exist on your right table, it is NULL, and you are asking to retrieve only the rows where fk_osname is = "AIX"`

you can do `WHERE (f.fk_osname = "AIX" OR f.fk_osname IS NULL)`

Comment: this also does not work but the answer from Ike Walker works fine